# Improve a function input without the comma in R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I am trying to simplify a function input. The function is to input a scholar's name and get their google scholar search result page.

The current input is `get_academics <- function("Stephen", "Hawking")` and I am wondering if there's a way to make the input `get_academics <- function("Stephen Hawking")` and the function still works instead. This is because it's a person's name and it's strange to write down a comma inbetween.

```
get_academics <- function(q, b){

  text <- paste0("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=", q, "+", b)

  return(text)
}
```

Current function input

```
get_academics("Stephen", "Hawking")
```

Desired function input

```
get_academics("Stephen Hawking")
```

Comment: just adjust your function to have only one argument. Drop `b` and adjust the `text` string as well.

Comment: @AlexB right but then it would become like `get_academics("Stephen+Hawking")`. While it's better than writing the comma, there's still a "+" sign. The link uses a "+" to separate the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to replace spaces with `+` characters:

```
get_academics <- function(name){
  name <- gsub(" ", "+", name, fixed = TRUE)

  paste0("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=", name)
}

get_academics("Stephen Hawking")
#[1] "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Stephen+Hawking"
```

Comment: Thanks! A nice play with gsub.

Answer (score 1):

A split based option(see Notes):

```
 get_academics <- function(q){
   split_name <- unlist(strsplit(q,"\\s"))
   q <- split_name[1]; b <- split_name<-split_name[2]

   text <- paste0("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=", q, "+", b)

   return(text)
 }
```

Result:

```
 get_academics("Stephen Hawking")
[1] "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Stephen+Hawking"
```

**NOTES**

- This may fail if space is greater than one
- It will also fail if a user uses a different delimiter e.g `-`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Personally, I think I'd prefer Roland's solution in this case because the one line of play with gsub is just easier for me to maintain the function in the long run. Many thanks again!